# jquery form with tree traversal

Tags: jquery, forms, tree-traversal

I got this school task to make this form. The * marks has to be filled if it doens't the message appears that you have to fill it (this has to be a red colored). That's all. 
Don't be hard on me.

```
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("ready", geladen);
        function geladen(){

             console.log("geladen");
            // zodra een veld verlaten wordt moet gecontrolleerd worden
        }
        function controlleerVerplicht(event){
            // controlleer of er niets is ingevuld
                    if ( $('input*').val().length < 1 ){

            $("*").css("border", "2px solid red").next().text("Dit veld is verplicht");

            }

            else ($("*").css("border", "2px solid green").next().text("Het is succesvol gedaan"));
                // en zet in dat geval de tekst "Dit veld is verplicht" in de span in dezelfde paragraaf
            }

        function checkAcceptatie(){

            console.log("check acceptatie");

            if ($("input:checked").length==1){

                $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");

                }


        }           
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="formulierverwerker.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                NAW
            </legend>
            <p>
                <label for="naamveld">Naam: *</label>
                <label for="dhr">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" id="dhr" />
                    dhr. </label>
                <label for="mevr">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" id="mevr" />
                    mevr. </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="naamveld" class="verplicht" />
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="straatveld">Straat:</label>
                <input type="text" name="street"  id="straatveld" />
                <label for="straatveld">Huisnummer: *</label>
                <input type="text" name="huisnummer"  id="huisnummerveld" class="verplicht" />
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="postcodeveld">Postcode: * </label>
                <input type="text" name="zip" class="verplicht" id="postcodeveld" />
                <label for="stadveld">Stad:</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" class="verplicht" id="stadveld" />
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Contact
            </legend>
            <p>
                <label for="emailveld">Email:
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="emailveld" />
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="telefoonveld">Telefoon:
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="telefoonveld" />
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button name="action" value="send" type="submit" >
                    Verstuur
                </button>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: `*` is a css/jQuery selector for all elements; why don't you add class `required` to those elements that are required instead?